# How to I print out a specific item from an arraylist based on a string entered

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, println

I have an `ArrayList` that holds contacts. Each contact is assigned an `ID` by the user when created. How do I reference that `ID` to print out the details of the contact. For example:
`Contact ID = 1`.  I want to call `1` from the `arrayList` and print Jone Smith, 123 West St etc..

Here is how I am creating the `ArrayList`:

Main Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


  public class ContactList {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int type = 0;
    while(type != 4){
    System.out.println("Please select an option:");
    System.out.println("Add a Personal Contact: Enter 1");
    System.out.println("Add a Business Contact: Enter 2");
    System.out.println("Display Contacts List: Enter 3");
    System.out.println("4 to quit");

    type = input1.nextInt();

    if(type == 4){
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
        break;
    }
if (type==1 || type==2){

     Contact contact = null;
    //ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter ContactId : ");
    String contactId = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter First Name : ");
    String firstName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter Last Name : ");
    String lastName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter Address : ");
    String address = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter Phone Number : ");
    String phoneNumber = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter Email Address : ");
    String emailAddress = input.nextLine();

    if(type == 1){
       System.out.println("Please enter Birthday: ");
       String dateofBirth = input.nextLine();
       Contact pcontact = new PersonalContact(contactId, firstName, lastName, address, phoneNumber, emailAddress, dateofBirth);
       contacts.add(pcontact);

       for (Contact showcontact: contacts){
           System.out.println(showcontact.displayContact());}
    }

    else if(type == 2){
        System.out.println("Please enter Job Title: ");
        String jobTitle = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter Organization: ");
        String organization = input.nextLine();
        Contact bcontact = new BusinessContact(contactId, firstName, lastName, address, phoneNumber, emailAddress, jobTitle, organization);
        contacts.add(bcontact);

        for (Contact showcontact: contacts){
           System.out.println(showcontact.displayContact());}
    }

}
    if(type == 3){
        //System.out.println(contacts);
        for (Contact showcontact: contacts){
            System.out.println(showcontact.displayFullName());}
        }
    }     
}  
}
```

Parent Class:

```
public abstract class Contact {

String contactId;
String firstName;
String lastName;
String address;
String phoneNumber;
String emailAddress;

public Contact(String contactId,String firstName,String lastName, String address, String phoneNumber, String emailAddress)
{
    this.contactId = contactId;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.address = address;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
}
public void setContactId(String input){
    this.contactId = input;
}
public String getContactId(){
    return contactId;
}

public void setFirstName(String input){
    this.firstName = input;
}
public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String input){
    this.lastName = input;
}
public String getLastName(){
    return lastName;
}

public void setAddress(String input){
    this.address = input;
}
public String getAddress(){
    return address;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String input){
    this.phoneNumber = input;
}
public String getPhoneNumber(){
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setEmailAddress(String input){
    this.emailAddress = input;
}
public String getEmailAddress(){
    return emailAddress;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
   return ("ContactID: " + this.getContactId() + "\nFirst Name: " + this.getFirstName() + "\nLast Name: " + this.getLastName() + "\nAddress: " + this.getAddress() + "\nPhone Number: " + this.getPhoneNumber() + "\nEmail Address " + this.getEmailAddress());
}

public String displayFullName(){
    System.out.println("Contact List:");
    return ("ContactID: " + this.getContactId() + "\nFirst Name: " + this.getFirstName() + "\nLast Name: " + this.getLastName());
}

public String displayContact(){
    return ("ContactID: " + this.getContactId() + "\nFirst Name: " + this.getFirstName() + "\nLast Name: " + this.getLastName() + "\nAddress :" + this.getAddress() + "\nPhone Number :" + this.getPhoneNumber() + "\nEmail Address " + this.getEmailAddress());
}

}
```

Subclasses are Personal and Business they just override some of the parent class so don't know that they are of interest to this issue. If wanted I can post them though.

Comment: Well, you have to loop through the elements of the list until you find the one with the given ID, and then print its details. It would be much easier if you used a `Map<String, Contact>`, storing each Contact as a value associated with its ID as a key.

Comment: So in that array list  bean objects are there You want to refernce the specific objects by the ID in that object am I correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also recommend using a `Map<String, Contact>`, but just in case you don't want to do that, here is how to do it with your code:

```
System.out.println("Please enter ID of contact: ");
String soughtId = input.nextLine();

for (Contact showcontact: contacts)
{
   if (showcontact.getContactId().equals(soughtId))
           System.out.println(showcontact.displayContact());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be easier to use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) here. This is a datastructure that consists of key-value pairs. You can use your id as a key and the contact as a value. An example:

```
Map<String, Contact> contacts = new HashMap<String, Contact>();
contacts.put("anId", aContact);
contacts.put("anotherId", anotherContact);
...
contacts.get("anId"); // returns aContact
```

Iterating over it to print can be done like this:

```
for(String contactId : contacts.keySet(){
    System.out.println(contacts.get(contactId).displayFullName());}
}
```

Comment: Iterating over the `entrySet()` of the map would be more efficient.